# How to combine element-wise multiplication and matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm trying to combine element-wise multiplication and matrix multiplication for two matrix:

- Matrix 1 shape: (N, N, 3, 3)
- Matrix 2 shape: (N, N, 3, 1)

I would like to perform element-wise operation for the first two dimensions (N, N), and matrix multiplication for the last two dimensions. The goal is to get a (N, N, 3, 1) matrix.

I was not able to find a good operation in numpy, may I know if there is a proper operation for this? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like `einsum` might be what you're looking for, but Divakar might figure out the expression before I do.

Comment: I think they want `einsum('ijkl,ijlm->ijkm', matrix1, matrix2)`

Comment: `maul/@` should work

Comment: Thanks! np.einsum('ijkl,ijlm->ijkm', matrix1, matrix2) works well!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want this. This is essentially matrix multiplication of the inner `(3, 3)` and `(3, 1)` shaped matrices.

```
import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(2, 2, 3, 3)
>>> b = np.random.rand(2, 2, 3, 1)
>>> c = np.matmul(a, b)
>>> c.shape
(2, 2, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Equivalently, `a @ b` gives exactly the same result (look up array broadcasting in numpy).